# How to get index of a key value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
    var myObj={
        age: null,
        anothercolumn: null,
        caseNum: null,
        casecount: null,
        casecountfgfg: null,
        city: null,
        country: null,
        county: null
   }
```

I have to change key name which is at 3rd position.
The information I have only the new key name and position .

something like

```
myObj[2] = 'new value'
```

please suggest

Comment: Here is the problem: Associative arrays do not have the same order by default in every browser. Always make sure to sort the keys alphabetically before changing them, as you might have surprises in some browsers.

Comment: @Tushar OP wanted to change the key's name. As well as you cannot guarantee the index of object's keys.

Comment: @blex : so instead of just position ,I need the info which key I am going to modify ,is that correct

Comment: What is the use-case? Can you add complete code with explanation of what you're trying to do

Comment: Having the key is better, but if you only have the position, make sure to get the keys using `Object.keys(myObj)`, sort them, and get the key at the index you want.

Comment: @blex *but if you only have the position* ... there is no position

Comment: I have key info now ,adding new and deleting old works for me .thanks

Answer (score 2):

Be *really careful*! Before ES2015 the order of property keys was not specified. So it just can change and is different from browser to browser.

[In ES2015 the order is specified as the order of creation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys).

So you **can not do what you want**.

The only possible way is to create a new Object and apply the keys in the order you want. I can just recommend to **not depend on the order of Object Keys**!

Answer (score 2):

As @Lux has stated, before `ES2015` the order of property keys was not specified. So it just can change and is different from browser to browser. However, a ***work around*** would be to ***loop through the object*** and ***get the key value info*** and ***see what key you want to replace***, then ***loop around the object replacing the key you want to replace*** as below:

```
    var myObject =[{"apple":"1"},{"ball":"3"},{"cat":"wer"},{"Nepal":"beautiful"},{"cat":"wer"}];//mock object
            for (var key in myObject) {
        if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + JSON.stringify(myObject[key]));
        }
    }
//if i want to replace all the cat key, then:
    for (var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
        myObject[i].catReplaced = myObject[i]['cat'];
        delete myObject[i].cat;
    }
```

**PLUNKER:**[Removing a particular key from an object](http://plnkr.co/edit/lOlBpWX7AJYyBOMFaenQ?p=preview)